# Scikit-learn roc_curve: why is thresholds [0] set to have values ​greater than 1?

Tags: scikit-learn, roc

I know that to plot what looks like a reasonable ROC curve, one needs to have a threshold that incorporates 0 data points; but why not set this value to 1?
shouldn't it be taken for granted that there are no certain predictions (ie that they have a probability equal to 100%)?
Looking at the default setting it seems possible to have predictions with probability equal to 1, I don't understand why.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html):

> thresholds : ndarray of shape = (n_thresholds,)
>
> Decreasing thresholds on
> the decision function used to compute fpr and tpr. thresholds[0]
> represents no instances being predicted and is arbitrarily set to
> max(y_score) + 1.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*incorporates 0 data points*"?

Comment: What if the prediction isn't a probability?

Comment: @desertnaut
that assuming the case of a binary element classification (1,0), it is necessary to know (in order to draw the correct ROC curve) which threshold classifies all data as 0.
At least so I understood, don't you agree?

Comment: @Calimo 
If it were not a probability he would be wrong, I think that's what I was told in the answer below (thanks for the tip)

Comment: I agree, but "*incorporates 0 data points*" is an extremely poor description of what you actually mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ROC curve can be generated using any measure of confidence, not just predicted probabilities.  In particular, in sklearn the `decision_function` method can be used instead of `predict_proba`.  (This is important; e.g., SVMs don't naturally produce probabilities, but signed distance to the hyperplane makes for a fine rank-ordering for ROC purposes.)

> shouldn't it be taken for granted that there are no certain predictions (ie that they have a probability equal to 100%)?

That's also not necessarily true: decision trees with a pure leaf will have probability prediction exactly 1, and even a logistic regression model might predict something that is rounded to 1 due to numerical precision limitations.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much; I did not think about this useful generalization.
In theory then since the method is the same, could I compare the ROC curve of an SVM with that of a binary classifier, based on probability?